# Trouble connecting Clickhouse to SSL-enabled PostgreSQL Table: How to fix?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssl, clickhouse, external-tables

**Clickhouse SSL Connection Issue with PostgreSQL Table**

I'm currently facing an issue when attempting to connect Clickhouse to a PostgreSQL table. My setup works well in a local non-SSL environment with the following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not exists {table_name} as postgresql('127.0.0.1:5432', 'postgres', 'transactions', 'postgres', {PASSWORD});
```

It works fine!

However, when replicating this process on my production server where an SSL connection is mandatory, I encounter the following error:

```
failed: FATAL:  SASL authentication failed
failed: FATAL:  SSL required
. (POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_FAILURE) (version 23.4.2.11 (official build))
```

For context, Clickhouse is running locally in Docker in my current setup.

I've thoroughly searched the available Clickhouse documentation and reviewed numerous opinions and related issues on the topic, but a solution or a parameter enabling SSL use seems elusive.

I'm turning to StackOverflow in hopes of finding a solution to my issue: How should I correctly configure an SSL connection from Clickhouse to PostgreSQL?

Also, I plan to contribute to the Clickhouse community by ensuring the solution to this issue is added to the Clickhouse documentation.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What error, if any, gets reported in the database server's log file?

Comment: @jjanes error.log + server.log [here](https://pastebin.com/my0prZgY)

Comment: That isn't the database server log I was hoping for.  It looks like maybe an app server log, or a connection pooler log, or maybe the clickhouse database server log, but I'm looking for PostgreSQL database server log.

Comment: That looks like the PostgreSQL client Clickhouse uses does not support SSL connections. Ask Clickhouse.

Comment: try to define openssl/client settings in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/

look https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server_configuration_parameters-openssl for details

Comment: found your thread about the issue on clickhouse github: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/50528 . unfortunately no progress yet